# Chrome Extensione, hide a combo box in reporting services filter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, reporting-services

The purpose of my chrome extension is that when you choose a value of a combo on the page, another combo is hidden (or not). The purpose of this extension is to bypass some structural limitations of reporting services.
Il manifest it is the seguent:

```
{
    "name": "HideMe!",
    "description": "Google Chrome extension!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["activeTab",
    "contextMenus","scripting"],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["background.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The js file it is the seguenet:

```
if (isReady()) {
  init();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', onReadyStateChange);
}

function isReady() {
  var page = document.readyState;
  return page === 'interactive' || page === 'complete';
}

function onReadyStateChange() {
  if (isReady()) {
    document.removeEventListener('readystatechange', onReadyStateChange);
    init();
  }
}

function init() {


    const menu = document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue");
    menu.addEventListener("change",function(){
        let inputvalue = menu.value;
        if (inputvalue==='Year and Month') {
            document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl11_txtValue").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl11_txtValue").classList.remove("disable");
            document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl13_txtValue").classList.remove("disable");
      //  block of code to be executed if the condition is true
        }else{
            document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl11_txtValue").classList.add("disable");
            document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl13_txtValue").classList.add("disable");
        }
        
        });
}
```

The problem is that when the page loads, the "ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue" menu is not found because the page is not loaded yet.
The error I'm getting is the following
background.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at init (background.js:25:7)
at background.js:4:3

I also tried to use the "window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) =>" method by inserting them in there but the content doesn't seem to be executed.

Comment: Use can use MutationObserver to wait for the elements.